# web sharing on lion - odd behavior

Tags: macos, webserver, file

In my Lion local web sharing folder, I noticed that I cannot change any of the files without typing in my password.

I also noticed that there's a folder called postgresql there.

I don't remember having these behaviours before with Snow Leopard, are these new changes that Lion OS brings?

Comment: Does `ls -lad ~/Sites/` start with `drwxr-xr-x  5 yourname`? If not, you can restore the default owner with `sudo chown $USER ~/Sites/` or permissions with `chmod 751 ~/Sites/`.

Comment: Or do you mean `/Library/WebServer/Documents/`?

Comment: @Lri I mean `/Library/WebServer/Documents/`. Thank you for helping.

Comment: I noticed that my Documents folder gives me read access only. Is this new since Lion? Also is the postgresql folder new since Lion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permissions of some folders did change to more restrictive on Lion. I don't know about 10.6, but /Library/WebServer/Documents/ is owned by root and has 751 permissions on 10.8 as well.

I don't have any postrgesql folder by default on 10.8, but 10.7 might have had one.

Files are normally meant to put be to ~/Sites/ and accessed from `http://localhost/~username/`. The URLs can be made shorter by [adding virtual hosts](https://superuser.com/a/384088/69039).

You could change the owner back to yourself with `sudo chown -R $USER /Library/WebServer/Documents/`.